# Calculate number of days left from nearest date in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a list like this:

```
dates = ["2020-05-08","2019-02-22", "2014-08-16"...........]
```

And a DF like this:

```
date               .....
2020-12-19         .....
2015-06-01         .....
2018-03-06         ....
......
```

I want to create another column named "daysLeft", which count, the days from the nearest date.

For example.

If today is 24th Dec, then "1" day is left for chrismas. But if today is 26th Dec, "-1" day is left for Christmas. (Subtract date with nearest date)

Comment: What is the fixed date you are subtracting from?

Comment: What is the fixed date that you are subtracting from?

Comment: There is no fixed date. I want to fetch the closest date and calculate the number of days left

Comment: You can think of it as "Calculate the days left (before or after) to the nearest birthday date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure in this answers your question, but this might be a step in the right direction:

```
#This Function Converts String to DateTime Object for Date Manipulation
from datetime import datetime
def make_date(any_value):
    return datetime.strptime(any_value, '%Y-%m-%d')

#We apply thr Function to the list
dates = ["2020-05-08","2019-02-22", "2014-08-16"]
dt_obj = list(map(make_date, dates))

#We apply the function to the DataFrame
date_df_list=["2020-12-19", "2015-06-01", "2018-03-06" ]
import pandas
date_df=pandas.DataFrame(date_df_list, columns=["date"])
date_df['date'] = date_df['date'].astype(str)     #Each object needs to be converted to String for Function
date_df_yyyymmdd = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['date']) #Initialise Empty DataFrame
date_df_yyyymmdd['date'] = date_df['date'].apply(make_date)


#In this example we Find Difference in Dates for the first date of list
#Similarly we can find for all the other dates in the list
date_df['daysLeft'] = date_df_yyyymmdd['date'].apply(lambda x: (x-dt_obj[1]).days)
print(date_df)
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, please do consider upvoting it also so that others with a similar problem can find it easily. Thanks!